# On page load, create X number of divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a weird idea where I want to ping number of records in a database with PHP, store number of records as `$x`, then create `$x` number of divs on a page.

I can currently return number of records with this code, so getting number of records is the easy part:

```
$getAllRecords = $test->getAllCats();//normal query db records return all method
$howManyCats = count($getAllRecords);//how many total cats?
```

What is best method to go about this? Would this all be within jQuery? Can I handle this just in PHP? What are you thoughts, and any suggestions if you have done this or something similar to this before?

Comment: This is off topic as primarily opinion-based. For example I would send the number to the client and have the client write the divs instead of passing html across the net

Comment: You could do it with jQuery or php. doesn't matter which one. just loop x number of times each time adding a div to a string, then print the string to html is how i would probably do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery:

```js
// var num = <?=$howManyCats?>;
var num = 10;
$(function() {
  var html = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    html.push('<div id="cat' + i + '">' + i + '</div>');
  }
  $("#container").append(html.join('')); // append all in one go

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: how would i pass in the php variable of number of cats into the javascript num var?

Comment: Uncomment the first line! Comment the second

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to insert the correct number of rows and then use echo to add the divs to the page.

```
$getAllRecords = $test->getAllCats();//normal query db records return all method
$howManyCats = count($getAllRecords);//how many total cats?

for ($i = 1; $i <= howManyCats ; $i++) {
    echo '<div/>'
}
```